# GAE NDB performance of ComputedProperty versus on-demand lookup of related-model count

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Using Google App Engine, I am just curious if anyone can illuminate the performance characteristics (reading & writing) of using a `ComputedProperty` versus calculating-on-demand a count of a related model.

A ComputedProperty has the distinct benefit of allowing indexing on a property, but I am just curious about how fast reading & writing are in comparison.

For example, given two models:

```
class Car(ndb.Model):
  owner_key = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Owner', indexed=True)

class Owner(ndb.Model)
   def cars_count(self):
       ndb.query(Car.owner_key == self.key).count()

   cars_count_prop = ndb.ComputedProperty(cars_count)
```

The question really breaks down into something like the following:

1. how much slower is writing `Owner` because it has the `cars_count_prop`?
2. how much faster is reading `cars_count_prop` than `cars_count`?

Or, in other words:

1. what is the asymptotic computational complexity (big-O) of reading and writing each?
2. what is the average case computational complexity - for people other than [Jay Leno](http://www.jaylenosgarage.com/) (i.e. small numbers of `Car` instances per `Owner`)?
3. How much of the wait for reading and writing is computational complexity, and how much is database / memcache lookups?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Evry time you update an owner entity the query will be recomputed. That can't be good. The complexity of the query isn't the issue. But if you really want to know, you have to benchmark it.

Comment: Thank you, Guido. I would hazard a guess that the `ComputedProperty` alternative would be preferable in those cases where it is rarely written but often read.

Comment: Even in those cases the computed property doesn't save you anything -- it still runs the query each time you ask for its value!  The point of using a computed property is when you want to *index* the computed value. But this example is not a good candidate for that, since the stored value goes stale each time a car is added to (or removed from) a given owner. You could fix this by adding a read+write cycle to the owner whenever they acquire or dispose of a car, but then you might as well manually store the count...

Comment: Oh yes, I see. That's exactly what [the docs say](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#computed), so I should have noted that. Thanks for your comment. Quite helpful.